# Showing rotation is a symmetry of given Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

I have the Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2) - ax^2 -by^2 -cy^3$. I am trying to work out the conditions that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ must satisfy so that rotations around the origin, i.e. $x'=x-y\theta+O(\theta^2)$ and $y'=x\theta+y+O(\theta^2)$, are a symmetry of $L$.

I have to work with the definition "a transformation is a symmetry if $L' = L + \theta\frac{dF(x,y,t)}{dt} + O(\theta^2)$".

After a few lines of algebra I get the following:

$L' = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2) - ax^2 -by^2 -cy^3 + \theta(2xy(a-b)-3cxy^2) + O(\theta^2)$
$L' = L+ \theta(2xy(a-b)-3cxy^2) + O(\theta^2)$

and so $\frac{dF(x,y,t)}{dt}=2xy(a-b)-3cxy^2$. But since this will always be a function of $x$ and $y$ regardless of the values $a,b$ and $c$ take, I don't see why these constants must satisfy any conditions. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly finished.
Consider your result

> $$L' = L+ \theta(2xy(a-b)-3cxy^2) + O(\theta^2).$$

In order to make
$$\theta(2xy(a−b)−3cx^2) = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \text{ and } y$$
you must have the conditions $a=b$ and $c=0$.

Comment: This is what I thought should be the condition as it makes intuitive sense, but why must $2xy(a-b) - 3cxy^2$ be zero? If I had $a=2, b=1, c=1$ for example, then $\frac{dF(x,y,t)}{dt}=2xy-3xy^2$. So because this is just a function in $x$ and $y$ it does not contradict the $L' = L + \theta\frac{dF(x,y,t)}{dt} + O(\theta^2)$ definition of symmetry I have to work with.